# How to see if there is a match (in percentage) between 2 columns from different tables

Tags: mysql, python-2.7

I have 2 MySQL different tables from 2 sources which contains names of venues!I want to find a match between this names to store it in a third table!The idea is to find a percentage that allows me to know that the names refers to the same venue!If they match >= 75 % is talking about the same venue!This way I can chose for the third table a single name for a venue (either the name form table 1 or the one from table 2 ).I tried something with MATCH AGAINST sintax but I didn't get the desired results!Thanks in advance! I expect also ideas which can be done using python!

For i.e :
I have table 1 :

```
ID | Name
---------
1  | Ministry of Sound
2  | 4 Elements
3  | Blue Marlin Ibiza
```

and Table 2 :

```
ID | Name
---------
1  | Ministry Sound
2  | Four Elements
3  | Blue Marlin
```

if row 1 from table 1 match >= 75% with row 1 from table 2 . In table 3 I would copy the name from table 1

Comment: Show us some sample data and expected result.  Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: OK,thanks for advice Juan Carlos Oropeza

Comment: Try `SELECT A.venue_name, B.venue_name FROM venue_table_1 AS A LEFT JOIN venue_table_2 AS B ON A.venue_name LIKE CONCAT('%', B.venue_name, '%')` to see what venues have similar names.

Comment: Thanks @gr1zzly be4r but this doesn't work very well.It creates much confusion

Comment: What you mean `>=75%`? What formula you use or use the `MATCH AGAINST` ratio? For example first row are match `2 of 3` words so 66%?  but maybe also depend on word sizes?

Comment: I'm interested to find the best match between this 2 columns! And when I say "match" I mean the best approach between them so I think that they need to be almost the same!

Comment: I tried using levenshtein edit distance but this applies to characters and this  works but I'm not completely satisfied ! I'm thinking to use it but for the hole sentence!

Answer (score 0):

I create a function to compare the matching

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0a995/1)**

```
CREATE FUNCTION F_TEST (_ID INT, _NAME varchar(14)) 
RETURNS float
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN 
  DECLARE match_ratio float;    

    SELECT (MATCH (`Name1`)
           AGAINST (_NAME IN BOOLEAN MODE)) INTO match_ratio 
    FROM Table3 
    WHERE `ID` = _ID;

  RETURN match_ratio;
END//
```

**QUERY**

```
SELECT `ID`, `Name1`, `Name2`, F_TEST(`ID`, `Name2`) AS score 
FROM Table3
ORDER BY score DESC;
```

**OUTPUT**

```
| ID |             Name1 |          Name2 |    score |
|----|-------------------|----------------|----------|
|  3 | Blue Marlin Ibiza |    Blue Marlin | 0.455289 |
|  1 | Ministry of Sound | Ministry Sound | 0.455289 |
|  2 |        4 Elements |  Four Elements | 0.227645 |
```